# append select option on body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I am trying to append select field on body, when any of options is selected.

But this is being appended on selected option itself because i am appending it with options.
I don't know how to append it on body now.

How can i append select field on body when i click on option?

**Here is javascript code -**

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('change keypress', 'select ', function (e) {

        alert($('select option:selected(this)').append("<select><option>Four</option></select>"));

    });
});
```

And a fiddle- [**Appending Select Box**](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/yT6Y5/84/)

Comment: Problem here: `$('select option:selected(this)')`. Check docs http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: @elclanrs, It is going same after i removed this.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you show your original HTML, and what you want the DOM to change to when the user selects an option?

Answer (score 1):

You're really close, it just needs to be:

```
 $(document).on('change keypress', 'select ', function (e) {
    $(this).append("<option>Four</option>");
 });
```

Or (not sure if you wanted to add an option to the current select, or add a new one):

```
$(document).on('change keypress', 'select ', function (e) {
    $('body').append("<select><option>Four</option></select>");
 });
```

Comment: just another select box on body i needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(function() {
  $(document).on('change keypress', 'select', function (e) {
   var value=$(this).val();
    $('body').append("<select><option value="+value+">"+value+"</option></select>");

  });
 });
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yT6Y5/86/)